Misalignment when overlaying Python-generated raster tiles on EPSG:3395 nautical chart
I'm working on a project to visualize ship location data on nautical charts using the EPSG:3395 coordinate system. I have a set of latitude and longitude coordinates for various ships, and I want to render these as green points on tile images that can be overlaid on nautical charts.
Here's what I'm trying to do:

Load ship location data from a JSON file.
Convert the coordinates from WGS84 (EPSG:4326) to EPSG:3395.
Generate tile images for different zoom levels, drawing green diamond shapes for each ship location.
Overlay these generated tiles on EPSG:3395 nautical charts.

The problem I'm encountering is that when I overlay the generated tile images on the EPSG:3395 nautical charts, there's a noticeable misalignment. However, when I overlay the same images on a standard web map (which I assume uses Web Mercator projection), the alignment seems correct.
The dislocated image looks like this:

When I render the tiles using Geoserver it looks normal:

Here's my code:
import os
import time
import cv2
import numpy as np
import orjson
from geo_tool import tile as tile_util
from pyproj import CRS, Transformer
from rtree import index

TILE_SIZE = 256
PADDING_PIXEL = 10

proj_wgs84 = CRS.from_epsg(4326)
proj_3395 = CRS.from_epsg(3395)
transformer_to_3395 = Transformer.from_crs(proj_wgs84, proj_3395, always_xy=True)
transformer_to_wgs84 = Transformer.from_crs(proj_3395, proj_wgs84, always_xy=True)


def draw_diamond(image, center, size, color):
    gap = 0
    points = np.array(
        [
            [center[0] + gap, center[1] - size + gap],
            [center[0] - size + gap, center[1] + gap],
            [center[0] + gap, center[1] + size + gap],
            [center[0] + size + gap, center[1] + gap],
        ]
    )
    cv2.fillPoly(image, [points], color)


def generate_tiles_for_zoom(zoom_level):
    max_tile = 2**zoom_level - 1
    return [
        (x, y, zoom_level) for x in range(max_tile + 1) for y in range(max_tile + 1)
    ]


def generate_tiles_for_zoom_range(zoom_level_start, zoom_level_end):
    return [
        generate_tiles_for_zoom(zoom_level)
        for zoom_level in range(zoom_level_start, zoom_level_end + 1)
    ]


def generate_map_tiles_cv(in_range_latlngs, x, y, z, bbox):
    tile_dir = "tiles"
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bbox
    tile_filename = f"{tile_dir}/{z}/{y}/{x}.png"
    extended_bbox = (
        min_x - (max_x - min_x) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
        min_y - (max_y - min_y) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
        max_x + (max_x - min_x) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
        max_y + (max_y - min_y) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
    )
    image = np.zeros(
        (TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL * 2, TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL * 2, 4),
        dtype=np.uint8,
    )
    positions = [
        (
            int(
                (latlng["x"] - extended_bbox[0])
                * (TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL * 2)
                / (extended_bbox[2] - extended_bbox[0])
            ),
            int(
                (extended_bbox[3] - latlng["y"])
                * (TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL * 2)
                / (extended_bbox[3] - extended_bbox[1])
            ),
        )
        for latlng in in_range_latlngs
    ]
    for px, py in positions:
        draw_diamond(image, (px, py), 2, (0, 255, 0, 255))
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.dirname(tile_filename)):
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(tile_filename))
    image = image[
        PADDING_PIXEL : TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL,
        PADDING_PIXEL : TILE_SIZE + PADDING_PIXEL,
    ]
    cv2.imwrite(tile_filename, image)


def main():
    with open("./position_7.json", "rb") as f:
        data = [
            {"x": x, "y": y}
            for latlng in orjson.loads(f.read())
            for x, y in [
                transformer_to_3395.transform(
                    float(latlng["lon"]), float(latlng["lat"])
                )
            ]
        ]

    tiles = [
        item for sublist in generate_tiles_for_zoom_range(3, 10) for item in sublist
    ]

    idx = index.Index()
    for i, latlng in enumerate(data):
        idx.insert(i, (latlng["x"], latlng["y"], latlng["x"], latlng["y"]))

    for x, y, z in tiles:
        bbox_wgs84 = tile_util.tile_to_bbox(x, y, z)
        min_x, min_y = transformer_to_3395.transform(bbox_wgs84[0], bbox_wgs84[1])
        max_x, max_y = transformer_to_3395.transform(bbox_wgs84[2], bbox_wgs84[3])
        bbox = (min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y)

        extended_bbox = (
            min_x - (max_x - min_x) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
            min_y - (max_y - min_y) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
            max_x + (max_x - min_x) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
            max_y + (max_y - min_y) / TILE_SIZE * PADDING_PIXEL,
        )
        rst = [data[i] for i in idx.intersection(extended_bbox)]

        if rst:
            generate_map_tiles_cv(rst, x, y, z, bbox)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I use html&leaflet to render tiles
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Leaflet Map</title>
    <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <style>
        #app {
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- Leaflet JS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script>
        const map = L.map('app', {
            crs: L.CRS.EPSG3395,
            layers: [
                new L.TileLayer('https://m12.shipxy.com/tile.c?l=Na&m=o&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}&'),
            ],
            zoomAnimation: false,
        });

        map.setView([32.1103, 120.0924], 10);

        new L.TileLayer("http://127.0.0.1:8081/tiles/{z}/{y}/{x}.png").addTo(map);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm handling the coordinate transformations or calculating the pixel positions within each tile, but I'm not sure where exactly the problem lies.
Questions:

What could be causing this misalignment when overlaying on EPSG:3395 charts?
Is there an issue with how I'm transforming coordinates or calculating pixel positions?
Are there any specific considerations I need to keep in mind when working with EPSG:3395 projection for nautical charts?

Sample data Download

can you add some detail on how you are overlaying the tiles on your map? actual code would be great

@ianturton  I have added the relevant code about how tiles are rendered on the map. If there is anything else that needs to be added, please let me know.
